# Why did Apache name it's Webservers Apache and Tomcat?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

As usual, when my girlfriend can't sleep, I have to talk about my work. Or what she says "Tell me something about servers".
So yesterday the topic was webservers and I told her about the commonly used Webservers like apache, nginx, Microsoft IIS.
At some point she was (really) interested but I couldn't answer.
Why are the webservers called Apache and Tomcat? My first assumption was that the Apache foundation always picked names from any military jets or vehicles or anything. But checking the other software I couldn't find a pattern.
So, does someone know why the webservers are called Apache and Tomcat?
I mean wow, a jet is fast and hmmm an apache is not that fast. So I am stuck.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better on e.g. [sf] or [su]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Apache

According to the FAQ in the Apache project website, the name Apache was chosen out of respect to the Native American tribe Apache and their superior skills in warfare and strategy.

## Tomcat

Tomcat started off as a servlet reference implementation by James Duncan Davidson, a software architect at Sun Microsystems. He later helped make the project open source and played a key role in its donation by Sun Microsystems to the Apache Software Foundation. The Apache Ant software build automation tool was developed as a side-effect of the creation of Tomcat as an open source project.

Davidson had initially hoped that the project would become open sourced and, since many open source projects had O'Reilly books associated with them featuring an animal on the cover, he wanted to name the project after an animal. He came up with Tomcat since he reasoned the animal represented something that could fend for itself. Although the tomcat was already in use for another O'Reilly title, his wish to see an animal cover eventually came true when O'Reilly published their Tomcat book with a snow leopard on the cover in 2003.

Note: you could find them all on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/).